# Solar photovoltaic diode current flow

Tags: semiconductor-physics, photoelectric-effect, solar-cells

When the PV cell is provided an external circuit, why do the electrons flow through the wire even when it can flow directly from within, between the p and n side?

What happens to the generated current in PV Si diode cell in absence of any load when it is provided sunlight.

Comment: Because current can't flow directly from p to n as long as there is a depletion layer.

Answer (score 0):

> when it can flow directly from within, between the p and n side

Because there is an internal area, the *[depletion layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depletion_region)*, that the charges can't cross. It is this layer that makes a diode work, and it takes quite a bit of energy to overcome it.

> What happens to the generated current in PV Si diode cell in absence of any load when it is provided sunlight

The electrons *briefly* flow into the top layer, as long as there are empty holes. Once those fill the cell reaches equilibrium and the current stops. This is essentially instantaneous. Electrons keep getting photoexcited after that, but they just give up their energy to heat and get recaptured on atoms again.

Comment: From a EE perspective: The "quite a bit of energy to cross it" is responsible for the diode's _[forward threshold voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Current%E2%80%93voltage_characteristic)_ (a.k.a., "forward voltage drop"). The current induced by a constant light source is approximately constant. With no external load, the current all flows across the junction, and the terminal voltage equals the forward drop. If it's short circuited, the current flows entirely through the short, and the terminal voltage is zero. Useful operating points lie somewhere in between those extremes.